# Go - Load data into three Struct using a common method

Tags: go, struct

I want to load data into three structs using a method(pointer) parsing a file. I am new to Go.

```
type a struct {
    a string
}

type b struct {
    b string
}

type c struct {
    c string
}

func main() {
    parse_file(filename)
}

//In below method, *l not sure how to define which can include 3 struct
func (l *l)parse_file(filename string) {
    // open a file line by line
    // if the line has value a then load into Struct a
    //If the line has value b then load into Struct b
    //If the line has value C then load into Struct c
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with how you have the lines in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a struct which embed the other 3 struct

See the sample

test.txt

```
a - This is A
b - This is B
c - This is C
```

Code

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type a struct {
    a string
}

type b struct {
    b string
}

type c struct {
    c string
}

type l struct {
    a
    b
    c
}

func main() {

    l := &l{}
    filename := "test.txt"
    l.parse_file(filename)

    fmt.Println("A : ", l.a)
    fmt.Println("B : ", l.b)
    fmt.Println("C : ", l.c)
}

// In below method, *l not sure how to define which can include 3 struct
func (l *l) parse_file(filename string) {
    // open a file
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // read line by line
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        switch {
        // if the line has value a then load into Struct a
        case strings.HasPrefix(line, "a -"):
            // add the data to the a object
            l.a = a{
                a: line,
            }

        //If the line has value b then load into Struct b
        case strings.HasPrefix(line, "b -"):
            // add the data to the b object
            l.b = b{
                b: line,
            }

        //If the line has value C then load into Struct c
        case strings.HasPrefix(line, "c -"):
            // add the data to the c object
            l.c = c{
                c: line,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the prefix `a -`  , `b -`  or `c -`, then you can remove it with `TrimPrefix`

```
line := strings.TrimPrefix(line, "a -")
```

Comment: Thanks Pratheesh so much. I also did the same, but calling the struct in the embedded struct was not right. Thank you